# Mongodb quering by id of creation range

Tags: mongodb

I don`t know how to search from an id range using mongodb (id represent the insertion order in the database).

Example: I wanna look up from element id 0 to element id 19 -> First 20 elements

Since i`m storing the ObjectId, how can i look up for this kind of search?

My structure:

**{ "_id" : ObjectId( "50e9ccb30364a89b9b286f7a" ),"dataCriacao" : Date( 1357499571496 ),"email" : "danielp@r7.com","nome" : "Daniel","version" : 0 }**

Does i have to create a separate id number?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can sort and filter by `_id` just like you can with any other field.  To get the first 20:

```
db.test.find().sort({_id: 1}).limit(20)
```

However, while `ObjectId` values begin with a one-second resolution timestamp of their creation, that doesn't guarantee they're strictly ordered by creation time if the records are created by multiple clients as `ObjectId`s are generally created driver-side (as opposed to centrally by the MongoDB server).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `CreatedOn` date field and sort on that.

Sorting on an `Id` is a bad idea because:
- they are not guaranteed to be incremental
- they are not ment to be used as a business value

Answer (score 0):

To find the first 20 users (for example):

```
db.users.find().limit(20)
```

If you want to do a search *between* e.g. `ObjectId("50ea0918ec661588c2000001")` and `ObjectId("50ea0918ec661588c200000c")`:

```
db.users.find({ _id: { $gt: ObjectId("50ea0918ec661588c2000001"), $lt: ObjectId("50ea0918ec661588c200000c") } })
```

However, the [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) is generated based on a number of fields (see link). There is no guarantee that they will be in a logical order.

Comment: Ok, so just to get it straight, if i do: db.users.find({_id: 1}).limit(20) and than db.users.find({_id: 20}).limit(20) nothing guarantee i'll get 40 distinct elements from database?

Comment: No, since _id: 20 will never exist. Default _id's look similar to '50ea0918ec661588c2000001'. You could however do db.users.find({ _id: { $gt: <lastseenObjectId>}}).limit(20). That will return 20 documents with an ObjectId greater then the last one you pulled in the previous query. The query is sorted by _id by default.